# Ubuntu and mysql server. Something isnt allowing me to connect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, remote-access

I have a question about mysql settings [remote connections and mysql on ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/questions/94054/remote-connections-and-mysql-on-ubuntu/94088#94088) now i want to figure out why i cannot connect.

I made sure bind-address was commented out. I can ping the server within the VM but i cannot ping it from within the VM using `mysqladmin --protocol=tcp --host=self_ip ping`. I also followed along and check if my ports were open and they look like they are. I setup samba on that VM and can access that with no problem as well. It looks like ubuntu does not have a firewall either (i figured this out before) so i am stumped why the server isnt allowing my connection.

Apparently the config file works on another person side http://www.pastie.org/742545

I am using Ubuntu 6.06 LTS just because of 'support' reasons. So hopefully this will be 'easy'?

Comment: i often forget to accept but i dont think that matters. Also many of my questions are wiki so i dont feel its right to accept. Anyways i looked at /var/log/ mysql .err and .log and both are empty

Comment: Run `sudo mysqld` by hand: you'll see the errors :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it's the last step from the linked question:

If logins are working on the machine, but permission is being denied remote machines, remember that MySQL performs access control using username, password and hostname (with wildcards permitted). You may need to adjust your grant tables.

Try logging into MySQL as root on the MySQL server and running:

```
# grant all on [database name].* to '[user name]'@'[remote client hostname or IP address]' identified by '[password]'
```

You might want to reduce the "all" permission to something more restrictive, depending on your access requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. When you use --host=self_ip Do you mean --host=127.0.0.1 or --host=192.168.NNN.NNN or do you mean literally --host='self_ip' ?

Because --host=self_ip literally typed may mean to actually call up a host on the network whose name is "self_ip"

Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

First locally establish:
Is mysql running at all (ps aux | grep mysql)?

Is mysql listening on any ports (netstat -ln | grep mysql)?

Can you connect to it?

(If you can't follow the procedure for resetting the root password [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html) (stop mysql, start from command line with skip-grant-tables. Also, a nice link for [Can't connect to [local] MySQL server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) straight from the ref manual.).

If it works on local then you problem is VM related.

Which VM is it? What kind of networking you use (bridged or NAT)?